# C# Timer to close Console Window after X seconds

Tags: c#, timer, console

newb here.

I am trying to understand how to write a timer to close my c# console applications so that I don't have to hit 'return' again to close the window (i've been using Console.Read(); to keep it open so i can see that the app ran as intended thus far) So i'm trying to make a small timer method, below is what i've found the far, but it doesn't run as I don't understand what/how to handle it I think.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lec044b_ForLoop_Sum
{
class Program
{
    public void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Announce Program");






        Console.WriteLine("Close Program Announcement");

        timer1_Tick(3000);


    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        myProgram.Play();

    }
}
```

}

I have researched this some, i've gone to the microsoft resources which are written for people who understand this stuff verses newbies and looked at a few blogs and just gotten more and more confused. Hoping for some help, which is appreciated kindly.

To sum up - i just want my console window to close automatically after 5 seconds. That is what i'm trying to do with a simple method. Ultimately I'll try to do this as a class or something, but i need to go in small steps so i understand.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lec044b_ForLoop_Sum
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Announce Program");
            Console.WriteLine("Close Program Announcement");
            Timer t = new Timer(timerC, null, 5000, 5000);
        }

        private void timerC(object state)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program myProgram = new Program();
            myProgram.Play();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

(note how it's not the `Timer` class from the namespace `System.Timers`, it's from the namespace `System.Threading`)

Comment: I attempted this, but the console was unable to find the 'Timer' that is specified in the first line of the timer code (Timer t = new TimerC,...)

Comment: My mistake completely. I didn't catch that you had added a new system library (using. System.Threading.Task;). This worked exactly as hoped. Thank you very much Anwarrex!

Comment: No problem, mistake was probably done from my part, as I had a couple of typos.

Answer (score 8):

Thread.Sleep will do what u want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Play();
}

static void Play()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Announce Program");
    Console.WriteLine("Close Program Announcement");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);            
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, it produced an error that read "The Name THREAD does not exist in current context")

Answer (score 0):

```
  Timer t = new Timer() ;
        t.Interval = 120000;
        t.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Application.Exit();
        };
        t.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The post with the check is the correct answer. HOWEVER, I just wanted to be clear to use System.Threading.Timer!
There is a System.Timers.Timer and a System.Windows.Forms.Timer I had a similar issue and the only one that worked perfectly for me WITHOUT locking up the UI was System.Threading.Timer
My implementation of this is below.

```
using System.Threading;

System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerC, null, 5000, 5000);

private void timerC(object state)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```